Unable to apply COUNTUNIQUE formula in an already existing formula
=COUNTIFS('OpEx Project Tracking- BB'!$E$4:$E,"="&A3,'OpEx Project Tracking- BB'!$Y$4:$Y,">" &TODAY())+COUNTIFS('OpEx Project Tracking- BB'!$E$4:$E,"="&A3,'OpEx Project Tracking- BB'!$Y$4:$Y,"")
So for reference this is a formula which gets me the no. of active projects going on corresponding to each category (&A3 is the category ref) taking Today's date as the reference and also returns me the blank columns
Now in this the issue is that One candidate can handle multiple ongoing projects and this formula doesn't give me that number it just gives the total no. of ongoing projects corresponding to each category
I now want it to give me the unique number of candidates who are handling these projects for ex one man named john handles 3 projects but now I want just 1 as my output as John himself handles all the projects currently this formula gives the output as 3
I tried to apply COUNTUNIQUE function on the entire formula and it didin't work
For ref - The candidates name column is -   OpEx Project Tracking- BB'!$B$4:$B

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Use filter(), like this:
=countunique(filter( 
  'OpEx Project Tracking- BB'!B$4:B, 
  'OpEx Project Tracking- BB'!E$4:E = A3, 
  ('OpEx Project Tracking- BB'!Y$4:Y = "") + ('OpEx Project Tracking- BB'!Y$4:Y > today())
))

See filter().
